# How to close context menu jquery on next click out of context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I implemented the jQuery ContextMenu plugin from Javascript Toolbox and it works beautifully. When I right click in certain specified areas, it opens the context menu that I want, so it works well in everything except for some thing:

When I clicks somewhere else out of context menu so its not closes. It is just closing on clikcing at some specific areas whereas i want to close it whenever outside context menu mouse is clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/documentation.php

Comment: Can you read the comment by yourself first? There's an option called [Edit].

Comment: I am using jquery.contextmenu.js where hide() function is already there as given above.

Comment: Visit [tour] @Ankit.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document.body).click(function(e){
   var $box = $('#ContextMenu');
   if(e.target.id !== 'ContextMenu' && !$.contains($box[0], e.target))
      $("#ContextMenu").hide();
});
```

You need to check for click events which bubbled up to document.body. In that event handler you look for the event target id and compare it with the element you do NOT want to include, plus all elements which are children of that excluded element.

$.contains() checks if a DOM node contains another node you specify. So

```
!$.contains($box[0], e.target)
```

means, if e.target does NOT contain the node $box[0]

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/